# Is there a Magento debug tool that lets me see database queries displayed in a similar manner to template path hints?

Tags: mysql, sql, debugging, magento

I have some corrupted data, an individual entry, in the database for my Magento installation. Since I can see the corrupted data displaying, I'd like to use a Magento extension to show me the database call displaying that data onscreen. Does such a tool exist? If not, what would be the best tool for SQL to gather this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the SQL statement used to load a collection by using `$collection->getSelect()`.  You'd have to narrow down the collection call first though, which might not be much help in your case.

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.ifuelinteractive.com/2009/10/18/logging-all-sql-in-magento/

Comment: I had that enabled. I suppose I was looking for something a little more "to-the-point" but it's possible this is the only option available.